# Not getting readings from Google analytics - Android

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I have 4 `fragments` and 2 `activities` in each one I have implemented the following code :

```
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

//...
private Tracker mTracker;
//...
AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getActivity().getApplication();
    mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
//...
@Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.i(TAG, ""+TAG); //TAG represents the name of the current activity/fragment     
    mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());

    super.onResume();
}
```

what I want to do is track the usage of each activity and fragment and get the current active users in real time and receive the info in my Google Analytics console, but I didn't manage to receive any data

**P.S.** So far I tested with only my device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by adding this line:

```
mTracker.setScreenName("Screen name: " + TAG);
```

final result

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.i(TAG, ""+TAG); //TAG represents the name of the current activity/fragment    
    mTracker.setScreenName("Screen name: " + TAG); //added line
    mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());

    super.onResume();
}
```